# Cron jobs not working anymore

Tags: cron

Cron jobs were working for months in the past but recently I had a high server load and now cron jobs aren't executing my php files (the same ones that were working before). When I check the cron log I see this which I believe has something to do with the issue:

`(CRON) EXEC FAILED (/usr/sbin/sendmail): Resource temporarily unavailable`

What do I need to do to fix this problem? I am running CentOS 7.

**EDIT:** I marked this as answered as I thought a process hanging was causing this issue. Today, I woke up and the same issue occurred. I wonder what could be causing this.

In the cron log, I see:

```
Oct 11 05:01:01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[25431]: starting 0anacron
Oct 11 05:01:01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[25444]: finished 0anacron
Oct 11 05:01:01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[25431]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Oct 11 05:01:01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[25450]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Oct 11 05:01:01 CROND[25434]: (CRON) EXEC FAILED (/usr/sbin/sendmail): Resource temporarily unavailable
Oct 11 05:01:01 CROND[25429]: (apache) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x0001
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed two things that look off in my mail log.

```
Oct  8 14:01:39 postfix/local[12886]: 5180C2D098A5: to=<N@mail.domain.com>, orig_to=<N>, relay=local, delay=1.1, delays=0.07/0.01/0/1, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "n")
Oct  9 04:19:10 postfix/local[12452]: C8F762D012D6: to=<root@mail.domain.com>, orig_to=<apache>, relay=local, delay=0.22, delays=0.13/0.02/0/0.07, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (cannot update mailbox /var/mail/root for user root. cannot open file: Is a directory)
```

Comment: Seems out of resource. Check yours limits, file descriptors, max process, etc.

Comment: @FedericoSierra I've increased the `limits.conf` and also `sysctl.conf` but I am still getting the same error in cron log. What user does cron use? I've increased for `apache` user which is the user that executes my php files. Maybe something with sendmail?

Comment: Look in your sendmail or message logs to see if there are any relevant messages. Take appropriate action.

Comment: @lain I am checking the `mail` and `messages` log but most of it has to do with `postfix` and not `sendmail`. I do notice a lot of queued mails (600+) but that is with postfix, not sure if postfix and sendmail are one of the same?

Comment: okay restarting apache fixed the problem so now I have to investigate why apache is preventing my crons to stop working.

Comment: "cannot update mailbox /var/mail/root for user root. cannot open file: Is a directory)" So /var/mail/root is a directory, not a file?

Answer (score 5):

> (CRON) EXEC FAILED (/usr/sbin/sendmail): Resource temporarily
>   unavailable

This isn't a cron problem. from exec(3):

> ```
>  The execl(), execle(), execlp(), execvp() and execvP() functions may fail
>  and set errno for any of the errors specified for the library functions
>  execve(2) and malloc(3).
> ```

From execve(2):

> ```
>  [ENOMEM]           The new process requires more virtual memory than is
>                     allowed by the imposed maximum (getrlimit(2)).
> ```

From malloc(3):

> ```
>    ENOMEM
>        Memory allocation error.
> ```

On most UNIX systems, any runaway process can consume enough resources to cause normal virtual memory allocations by non-runaway processes to also fail.

This is not a cron problem, it's a system resource, utilization, or tuning problem.

Comment: OP, I'm guessing your C7 box is a VPS or containerised system without swap.  When load increases, and no memory is available to fulfil cron's requests, what's a system to do?